# Excel VBA - Evaluate and index function returning #VALUE! error

Tags: excel, vba, indexing, evaluate

So I have an macro for a file in which there are three columns. The macro detect specific columns and rows in another workbook for my three columned file. See image below for workbook 1.

[image: input]

Then it should look at the rows and columns of workbook 2 (see below) and find the position of column A and B that match from workbook 1 and paste in the corresponding value of column C into workbook 2 (the value 1). However I keep getting #VALUE! error and I don't know why its happening.

[image: errors]

**FYI - the columns continue to 51 but cant fit in the image**

Below is the code for this macro:

```
Sub Location()
    Dim i As Long, k As Long, ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim lastrow As Long

    Set ws1 = Workbooks("Book3.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = Workbooks("Book4.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")
    lastrow = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For k = 2 To ws2.Cells(1, ws2.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            ws2.Cells(i, k).Value = ws2.Evaluate("IFERROR(INDEX(" & ws1.Range("B1:B" & lastrow).Address(0, 0, xlA1, 1) & ",AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(" & ws1.Range("A1:A" & lastrow).Address(0, 0, xlA1, 1) & ")" & _
            "/((" & ws1.Range("A1:A" & lastrow).Address(0, 0, xlA1, 1) & " = " & ws2.Cells(i, 1).Address(0, 0) & ")*(" & ws1.Range("C1:C" & lastrow).Address(0, 0, xlA1, 1) & "=" & _
            ws2.Cells(1, k).Address(0, 0) & ")),1)),"""")")
        Next k
    Next i

End Sub
```

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: Are both workbooks open at the time of running?

Comment: @ScottCraner Yeah they are, is it causing the problem?

Comment: No, if both are open.  and this worked on some but not others?

Comment: @ScottCraner Yeah it works if the column size in workbook 1 is roughly the same size as the row and column sizes in workbook 2. But if the column size of workbook 1 is much smaller than the row and column sizes of workbook 2, this error seems to appear.

Comment: your data is slightly different than the last question,so I have two question.  Is C always numbers? and, here you have the first three lines are the same A and B would you sum the numbers in c and return `9`?

Comment: @ScottCraner C is always numbers and yes sum the first three lines would be ideal

Comment: Try my answer below, it should be quicker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should have thought of this formula first:

```
Sub Location()
    Dim i As Long, k As Long, ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long

    Set ws1 = Workbooks("Book3.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = Workbooks("Book4.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")
    LastRow = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For k = 2 To ws2.Cells(1, ws2.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            ws2.Cells(i, k).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(ws1.Range("C1:C" & LastRow), ws1.Range("A1:A" & LastRow), ws2.Cells(i, 1), ws1.Range("B1:B" & LastRow), ws2.Cells(1, k))
            If ws2.Cells(i, k).Value = 0 Then ws2.Cells(i, k).Value = ""
        Next k
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: for future reference can I ask what caused the problem?

Comment: The first formula was written to cover all bases, it will return the first match regardless if numbers or text.  With C always being numbers SUMIF is quicker with less overhead.  The other formula is an array type formula and uses a lot of overhead.  It basically short circuits when referencing large data sets.  I should have asked the question about C being number last time.  sorry.

Comment: One last thing is it possible to set a range for the area that the code looks at. Rather than scanning everything below as it seems to overwrite values if any text from column A in workbook 1 is seen again in workbook 2 that is below the scanned area?

Comment: So that the amount of rows that it looks through is fixed.

Comment: you can change the Lastrow to a fixed row: `LastRow = 500` and the for loops to end at a specific row and column replaceing everything after the `To` in both lines to their respective row and column number.

Comment: 'For i = 2 To ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row' changing this to 'For i = 2 To ws2.Cells(50, 1).End(xlUp).Row' ? The overwriting only occurs in worksheet 2.

Comment: `For i = 2 to 100` and for j = 2 to 50` where your data on sheet 2 has 100 rows and 50 columns